# How do I check for a specific UITextField out of many?

Tags: ios, if-statement, ios6, uitextfield

Original question:
I have 3 UITextFields (nameField, locationField, and discriptionField) I need to have a if statement trigger on discriptionField only, however the way I have tried it (configured below) all 3 textfields perform setViewMovedUp. I have also tried 
    if([sender isEqual: discriptionField])
but I'm getting the same problem, all 3 textfields preform the method.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if (sender == discriptionField)
    {
        //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
        if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
           [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

My Solution:
Beginner mistake, I was calling that same method from another method without realizing it. Probably a poor way to solve the problem but here is my solution.

```
BOOL onlyDiscription = NO;

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
    {
        if ([sender isEqual:discriptionField])
        {
            //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
            if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
            onlyDiscription = YES;
        }
    }
}
-(void)keyboardWillShow {
    if (onlyDiscription) {
        // Animate the current view out of the way
        if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
        else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
        }
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {
    if (onlyDiscription) {
        if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
        else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
        {
            con = YES;
            [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
        }
    onlyDiscription = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use tag value and compare with tag value.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == discriptionField.tag)
    {
        //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
        if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
           [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

(or)

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if([sender isEqual:discriptionField]){
        if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
          [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :-( it's still calling the method

Comment: once check your textfiled names.

Comment: The names are correct. Is there a way to query a memory location?

Comment: No problems with the textFields anywhere else in the file. IBOutlets check out

Comment: My fault, it was launching the setViewMovedUp method from the next method (KeyboardWillShow)

Comment: ho gd,don't do that silly mistakes next time onwords it's my advise.

Comment: and when you want to equal condition don't use '=='.

Comment: I guess I did realize that KeyboardWillShow would get called automatically. I'm very new at this

Comment: Yeah I set a bool object to Yes in that if statement and put if statements over the other method calls to only call when equal bool = yes. problem a poor way to solve the problem but it works.

Comment: @user2340928:Accept the answer for clean up the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check like this

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
        if ([sender isEqual:discriptionField])
        {
             //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
              if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
              {
                   [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
              }
         }
}
```

Comment: That was my original attempt. I'm not sure why it's not working

Comment: Check your IBOutlet.It is connected to corresponding to each text field or not ?

Comment: I'm sure your doing wrong anywhere coz this method works proper if you have connected IBOutlet connect.And second thing i wanna tell you can do using tag.

Comment: You are right setViewMovedUp is being called from somewhere else. I commented it out in -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing but it still preformed from -(void)keyboardWillShow. :-(